# Parallel group topologies on Prüfer groups

Tags: topological-groups

Let $p$ be a prome number. Are there group topologies $\mathcal S$ and $\mathcal T$ on $\Bbb  Z_{p^\infty}$ such that
$$\mathcal T \nsubseteq \mathcal S,~~\mathcal S \nsubseteq \mathcal T$$

Answer (score 1):

I found a result in

*Cardinal invariants and independence results in the poset of precompact group topologies*, Alessandro Berarducci, Dikran Dikranjan, Marco Forti, Stephen Watson:

> Let $G$ be an infinite abelian group. The power set of the power set of $G$ can
>   be embedded in the poset of all Hausdorff group topologies on $G$.

So there are $A,B\in \mathcal P(\mathcal P(\Bbb Z_{p^\infty}))$ with
$$A\nsubseteq B,~~ B\nsubseteq A$$
$A$ and $B$ correspond to group topologies $\mathcal T$ and $\mathcal S$ with

$$\mathcal T \nsubseteq \mathcal S,~~\mathcal S \nsubseteq \mathcal T$$

But I do not know what $\mathcal T$ and $\mathcal S$ are.